Should amplify_outputs.json be git ignored?
I have an amplify project in React and I set up the front end pages already using React-Router etc.. and deployed on amplify and it was working great.
Now I want to add a backend so I ran:
npm create amplify@latest
it creates an amplify folder and creates amplify_outputs.json locally but when I try and deploy the latest commit I am getting a build error:
2024-10-03T15:49:01.443Z [INFO]: src/App.tsx(10,21): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../amplify_outputs.json' or its corresponding type declarations.

I see that amplify_outputs.json was added to the git ignore automatically but its not getting generated on the build so was wondering if I should remove it from the git ignore but it has a user_pool_client_id in it so Im pretty sure its supposed be generated on the build.

Hi I did have to add a amplify.yaml but through different testing this is what I needed:
version: 1
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline
        - npx ampx pipeline-deploy --branch $AWS_BRANCH --app-id $AWS_APP_ID
frontend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: dist
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - .npm/**/*
      - node_modules/**/*

Here is the link for this: https://docs.amplify.aws/react/deploy-and-host/fullstack-branching/mono-and-multi-repos/

amplify_outputs.json should be in in .gitignore since it can change as the environment or resources change.
First ensure that the backend is correctly deployed by running amplify push then amplify pull --appId APP_ID to regenerate the amplify_outputs.json file locally.
If the above doesn't work, try adding this to amplify.yml file:
preBuild:
  commands:
    - npm ci
    - amplify pull --appId APP_ID --envName ENV_NAME


Hi where do I add the amplify.yml file? Directly in my amplify directory?

Also when I try amplify pull --appId <myappID> --profile amplifyprofile I get the following error: ⚠️ Could not resolve either appId, environment name or both. Skipping environment check for function secrets and environment variables

The amplify.yml file should be placed in the root directory of your project.
Regarding the error, are you sure you are using the correct details? (AppId and profile)
When you specify --profile amplifyprofile, ensure that the profile is correctly configured in your AWS credentials file (~/.aws/credentials). Double-check the profile name matches and that it has the correct permissions.
Run amplify init again.

Adding another answer since I cannot comment due to lack of reputation.
Update your amplify.yaml with this:
version: 1
backend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm install
        - amplify pull --appId $AWS_APP_ID --envName $AWS_BRANCH
    build:
      commands:
        # Caching and building backend resources
        - npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline
        - npx ampx pipeline-deploy --branch $AWS_BRANCH --app-id $AWS_APP_ID

frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm install
    build:
      commands:
        # This should generate amplify_outputs.json locally
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: dist
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - .npm/**/*
      - node_modules/**/*

